# In Active reports, how to give Characters one font size and for Numerics one font size in Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, activereports

I am stuck with this issue since few hours :( Requirement is to display the dynamic data in **textbox** but the problem here is in the dynamic data characters should be of **Gill Sans MT, 15pt** and where ever Numerics(0,1,2..,9) come they should be Gill Sans MT, 20pt.

So i opted to use **Richtextbox** controll but unable to achieve the desired out put, code looks like

```
foreach (char c in richTextBox1.Text)
{
     if (c <= '9')
     {
         richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("GillSansMT", 20);
     }
     else
     {
         richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("GillSansMT", 15);
     }
}
```

Am trying to check each character in richtextbox, if suppose it is **numeric** by the virtue of above code am successful to find it out and its going in to the loop but the  **richTextBox1.SelectionFont** is not working default its taking **10pt** font size its not taking **20pt**.

Need some assistance for this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the SelectionFont to set the font but there is no selection.   you need to use the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties to set the selection then change its font.     Also, I would not recommend creating the new Font in a loop.  you should create the fonts outside the loop then reuse in the loop.

hope this helps.
http://activereports.grapecity.com